# Calling python files

Tags: python, input

I have a python file named dcftest.py with following (dummy) code

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

HERE I AM MISSING THE TICKER INPUT
df=yf.Ticker(ticker)
stockinfo = df.info

numshares = df.info['sharesOutstanding'] 
data = si.get_balance_sheet(ticker)              
cash = pd.DataFrame(data)
cash = cash.loc['cash']                    

FairPrice = sum(cash)/numshares
```

I would like to call this dcftest.py file from another testfile.py, but with the ticker input (e.g. 'XOM')
This simple routine works fine without ticker though

```
from dcftest import FairPrice
print(FairPrice)
```

So, long story short testfile.py should call dcftest.py with ticker input which should do the calculation and return FairPrice back to testfile.py.

Thanks

PS: Please do not mind the dcftest.py calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a file, but you can call a function. Put that code into a function that is called with the ticker symbol wanted.

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

def get_fair_price(ticker):
    df=yf.Ticker(ticker)
    stockinfo = df.info
    numshares = df.info['sharesOutstanding'] 
    data = si.get_balance_sheet(ticker)              
    cash = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cash = cash.loc['cash']                    
    FairPrice = sum(cash)/numshares
    return FairPrice
```

Example Call

```
from dcftest import get_fair_price
print(get_fair_price("XOM"))
```

Comment: TNX tdelaney very much.